# How to add fragment tab from another activity

Tags: java, android, fragment

I am asking for help about fragments. I have 3 fragments shown in my activity and the bottom navigation. I have a button on bottom navigation with the command to open another activity, where I have declared ImageViews (I can also use gridview..). What I want is to add a fragment into my main activity by clicking the ImageView. I have already declared a fragment and it is ready to use. In my MainActivity.java I have the code that is showing how many pages (fragment tabs) I want to show - Override public int getCount() { return 3 } - showing 3 pages, when i change it into 4, the fourth fragment will be shown. Thanks for answers and some help!

//edit// I am adding codes of each activity for better understand

**MainActivity.java**

```
    package com.example.mp.mmfinal2;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.Image;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuItemView;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    static final int TRY_ADD_RESULT = 1;

    protected Integer display_num;


    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_fullscreen:
                    Intent intent4=new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                    startActivity(intent4);
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_home:
                    Intent intent5=new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent5);
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_add:
                    Intent intent9=new Intent(MainActivity.this, TryAdd.class);
                    startActivityForResult(intent9, TRY_ADD_RESULT);
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

    };

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(TRY_ADD_RESULT requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == IMAGE_CLICK_RESULT) {
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                Integer result=data.getIntExtra("result");
                display_num = result;
                mSectionsPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }


    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        display_num = 3;


        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

        BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);


    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position){

                case 0:
                    Novtab tab1 = new Novtab();
                    return tab1;
                case 1:
                    Hostab tab2 = new Hostab();
                    return tab2;
                case 2:
                    Idntab tab3 = new Idntab();
                    return tab3;
                case 3:
                    Fortab tab4 = new Fortab();
                    return tab4;
                default:
                    return null;


            }
        }



        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return display_num;

        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "Google";
                case 1:
                    return "Seznam";
                case 2:
                    return "Stranka";
                case 3:
                    return "whatever";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
 }
```

**TryAdd.java** *(second activity called by click on bottomnav. item)*

```
    package com.example.mp.mmfinal2;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

/**
 * An example full-screen activity that shows and hides the system UI (i.e.
 * status bar and navigation/system bar) with user interaction.
 */
public class TryAdd extends AppCompatActivity {
    /**
     * Whether or not the system UI should be auto-hidden after
     * {@link #AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS} milliseconds.
     */
    private static final boolean AUTO_HIDE = true;

    /**
     * If {@link #AUTO_HIDE} is set, the number of milliseconds to wait after
     * user interaction before hiding the system UI.
     */
    private static final int AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS = 3000;

    /**
     * Some older devices needs a small delay between UI widget updates
     * and a change of the status and navigation bar.
     */
    private static final int UI_ANIMATION_DELAY = 300;
    private final Handler mHideHandler = new Handler();
    private View mContentView;
    private final Runnable mHidePart2Runnable = new Runnable() {
        @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Delayed removal of status and navigation bar

            // Note that some of these constants are new as of API 16 (Jelly Bean)
            // and API 19 (KitKat). It is safe to use them, as they are inlined
            // at compile-time and do nothing on earlier devices.
            mContentView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
        }
    };
    private View mControlsView;
    private final Runnable mShowPart2Runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Delayed display of UI elements
            ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
            if (actionBar != null) {
                actionBar.show();
            }
            mControlsView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    };
    private boolean mVisible;
    private final Runnable mHideRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            hide();
        }
    };
    /**
     * Touch listener to use for in-layout UI controls to delay hiding the
     * system UI. This is to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
     * while interacting with activity UI.
     */


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_try_add);

        mVisible = true;
        mControlsView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controls);
        mContentView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);


        // Set up the user interaction to manually show or hide the system UI.
        mContentView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                toggle();
            }
        });

        // Upon interacting with UI controls, delay any scheduled hide()
        // operations to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
        // while interacting with the UI.

        ImageView imview3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        imview3.setClickable(true);
        imview3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                Intent data = new Intent();
                data.putExtra("result", 4);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
                finish();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Trigger the initial hide() shortly after the activity has been
        // created, to briefly hint to the user that UI controls
        // are available.
        delayedHide(100);
    }

    private void toggle() {
        if (mVisible) {
            hide();
        } else {
            show();
        }
    }

    private void hide() {
        // Hide UI first
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.hide();
        }
        mControlsView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mVisible = false;

        // Schedule a runnable to remove the status and navigation bar after a delay
        mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mShowPart2Runnable);
        mHideHandler.postDelayed(mHidePart2Runnable, UI_ANIMATION_DELAY);
    }

    @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
    private void show() {
        // Show the system bar
        mContentView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
        mVisible = true;

        // Schedule a runnable to display UI elements after a delay
        mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mHidePart2Runnable);
        mHideHandler.postDelayed(mShowPart2Runnable, UI_ANIMATION_DELAY);
    }

    /**
     * Schedules a call to hide() in [delay] milliseconds, canceling any
     * previously scheduled calls.
     */
    private void delayedHide(int delayMillis) {
        mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mHideRunnable);
        mHideHandler.postDelayed(mHideRunnable, delayMillis);
    }
}
```

**gridempty.java**

```
package com.example.mp.mmfinal2;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.GridView;

public class gridempty extends AppCompatActivity {
    GridView gridView;

    String[] values = {
            "Stranka1",
            "Stranka 2"
    } ;

    int[] images = {
            R.drawable.add,
            R.drawable.home
    } ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gridempty);

        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.griView);
        GridAdapter gridAdapter = new GridAdapter(this, values, images);
        gridView.setAdapter(gridAdapter);

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


            }
        });


    }
}
```

**GridAdapter**

```
package com.example.mp.mmfinal2;

import android.content.Context;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by mp on 06.09.2017.
 */

public class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {



    Context context;
    private final String [] values;
    private final int [] images;
    View view;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public GridAdapter(Context context, String[] values, int[] images) {
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
        this.images = images;
    }



    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return values.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if(convertView == null){
            view = new View(context);
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.single_item, null);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageview);
            TextView textview = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview);
            imageView.setImageResource(images[position]);
            textview.setText(values[position]);


        }
        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `getCount()` return a global variable and set it's value as 3. After the click of the imageview Set the global variable to 4 and refresh your adapter data by calling `pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Hope it helps:)

Comment: Thanks for an advice, I tried, but I dont know the right exact code to write, I haven't that big knowledge about android studio and java, I started writing  apps 2 weeks ago :D, I appreciate your answer, I added the codes into a question above, if you still have time to help, I will be thankful!

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly edit a member variable on another activity, because switching to your second activity causes the first one to be stopped. The first activity is effectively no longer running after you have started the second activity. Therefore, your second activity has to be able to communicate it's changes to the first activity when it has finished. I would suggest looking into [startActivityForResult](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html). You will do something like this:

Activity 1:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    static final int TRY_ADD_RESULT = 1;

    protected Integer display_num;


    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_fullscreen:
                    Intent intent4=new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                    startActivity(intent4);
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_home:
                    Intent intent5=new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent5);
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_add:
                    Intent intent9=new Intent(MainActivity.this, TryAdd.class);
                    startActivityForResult(intent9, TRY_ADD_RESULT);
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

    };

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == TRY_ADD_RESULT) {
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                display_num = data.getIntExtra("result");
                mSectionsPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }


    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        display_num = 3;


        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

        BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);


    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position){

                case 0:
                    Novtab tab1 = new Novtab();
                    return tab1;
                case 1:
                    Hostab tab2 = new Hostab();
                    return tab2;
                case 2:
                    Idntab tab3 = new Idntab();
                    return tab3;
                case 3:
                    Fortab tab4 = new Fortab();
                    return tab4;
                default:
                    return null;


            }
        }



        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return display_num;

        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "Google";
                case 1:
                    return "Seznam";
                case 2:
                    return "Stranka";
                case 3:
                    return "whatever";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Activity 2:

```
public class TryAdd extends AppCompatActivity {
    /**
     * Whether or not the system UI should be auto-hidden after
     * {@link #AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS} milliseconds.
     */
    private static final boolean AUTO_HIDE = true;

    /**
     * If {@link #AUTO_HIDE} is set, the number of milliseconds to wait after
     * user interaction before hiding the system UI.
     */
    private static final int AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS = 3000;

    /**
     * Some older devices needs a small delay between UI widget updates
     * and a change of the status and navigation bar.
     */
    private static final int UI_ANIMATION_DELAY = 300;
    private final Handler mHideHandler = new Handler();
    private View mContentView;
    private final Runnable mHidePart2Runnable = new Runnable() {
        @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Delayed removal of status and navigation bar

            // Note that some of these constants are new as of API 16 (Jelly Bean)
            // and API 19 (KitKat). It is safe to use them, as they are inlined
            // at compile-time and do nothing on earlier devices.
            mContentView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
        }
    };
    private View mControlsView;
    private final Runnable mShowPart2Runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Delayed display of UI elements
            ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
            if (actionBar != null) {
                actionBar.show();
            }
            mControlsView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    };
    private boolean mVisible;
    private final Runnable mHideRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            hide();
        }
    };
    /**
     * Touch listener to use for in-layout UI controls to delay hiding the
     * system UI. This is to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
     * while interacting with activity UI.
     */


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_try_add);

        mVisible = true;
        mControlsView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controls);
        mContentView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);


        // Set up the user interaction to manually show or hide the system UI.
        mContentView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                toggle();
            }
        });

        // Upon interacting with UI controls, delay any scheduled hide()
        // operations to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
        // while interacting with the UI.

        ImageView imview3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        imview3.setClickable(true);
        imview3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                Intent data = new Intent();
                data.putExtra("result", 4);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
                finish();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Trigger the initial hide() shortly after the activity has been
        // created, to briefly hint to the user that UI controls
        // are available.
        delayedHide(100);
    }

    private void toggle() {
        if (mVisible) {
            hide();
        } else {
            show();
        }
    }

    private void hide() {
        // Hide UI first
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.hide();
        }
        mControlsView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mVisible = false;

        // Schedule a runnable to remove the status and navigation bar after a delay
        mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mShowPart2Runnable);
        mHideHandler.postDelayed(mHidePart2Runnable, UI_ANIMATION_DELAY);
    }

    @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
    private void show() {
        // Show the system bar
        mContentView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
        mVisible = true;

        // Schedule a runnable to display UI elements after a delay
        mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mHidePart2Runnable);
        mHideHandler.postDelayed(mShowPart2Runnable, UI_ANIMATION_DELAY);
    }

    /**
     * Schedules a call to hide() in [delay] milliseconds, canceling any
     * previously scheduled calls.
     */
    private void delayedHide(int delayMillis) {
        mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mHideRunnable);
        mHideHandler.postDelayed(mHideRunnable, delayMillis);
    }
}
```

You'll have to do some other stuff to handle actually getting that Fragment displayed, but I think the inter-activity code is more what you were asking about...

Comment: Thanks for an advice, I tried, but I dont know the right exact code to write, I haven't that big knowledge about android studio and java, I started writing apps 2 weeks ago :D, I appreciate your answer, I added the codes into a question above, if you still have time to help, I will be thankful!

Comment: Please see my edits and look carefully at the changes. Fair warning... i have not tested this, but it should get you most of the way there. Hope this helps! Let me know if you're still having problems.

Comment: At first thanks a lot! I tried to add the codes into both classes, but it didnt work, the  @override and the TRY_ADD_RESULT in the brackets after the onActivityResult and "result" after the get.IntExtra are red underlined (all in first activity) and IMAGE_CLICK_RESULT is full red. I tried some alt-enter stuff, but nothing did find out the problem.. I am editing my codes above just in case.. I appreciate your help so much!

Comment: Ah, the TRY_ADD_RESULT and IMAGE_CLICK_RESULT errors were a transcription error by me. Try the edits I made to onActivityResult. I am not sure about the @Override error... does it say something if you mouse over it?

Comment: I have already added the gridview codes, if its easier or something by gridview way, I can also set the itemclicknavigation onto dridempty.java and write the code you recommend to me.. I found out that griveiw will be more well-arranged for my application.. thanks for the answers!

Comment: After your edits, just ("result") after getIntExtra is red underlined, everything else has fixed. when I give mouse on it, it says: getIntExtra (String, int) in Intent cannot be applied to (String)

Comment: Yes, another result of not testing the code... turns out [getIntExtra requires a default argument as a second value](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html). So change that line to: display_num = data.getIntExtra("result", 3);

Comment: I tried, but the result on the next line changed into full red :D. Just in case, there is the condition I have now: if (requestCode == TRY_ADD_RESULT) {
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                display_num = data.getIntExtra("result", 3);
                display_num = result;
                mSectionsPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

Comment: Remove the "display_num = result;" line

Comment: On the second line, I tried the red result change into resultCode and it didn't show any errors, but when I clicked the image in the application, it didn't add a fragment, but It just bugged the fragment activity.

Comment: Can you describe what happened? How did it "bugged" the fragment activity?

Comment: Omg, it really worked! Thanks a fucking lot. I love you bro :D :D, just in interest, is there a similar solution for the gridview images?

Comment: Cool, glad it's working, happy to help :). If you just copy the onClick code for ImageView to the onClick for the gridview, it should do exactly the same thing.

Comment: Oh.. Again.. I found out this won't help me that much :D, because I just loaded the upcoming tab4 in the getItem function, so there is no way to change what the added fragment tab will be. I wanted to have like many images in the second activity and by them add many of different fragment tabs.. You really helped me and thanks, but is this also possible? :D

Comment: Yes, that is definitely possible. You have all the tools in place already. You can return whatever you want in the activity result intent. See [the Intent documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html). Based on whatever you send there, add fragments to the viewpager programmatically. If you need more help on this it's probably a good idea to open a new question at this point...